# WinUI 3 packaged application not creating folder in AppData

Tags: winui-3, appdata

In a WinUI 3 packaged application, I am trying to create a folder in `AppData\Local\MyApp`.  In my application startup I am doing the following:

```cs
public App()
{
  string apf = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
  string fp = Path.Combine(apf, "MyApp");
  Directory.CreateDirectory(fp);
}
```

This does not create any directory in AppData/Local.

When I run this:

```cs
public App()
{
  string apf = KnownFolders.GetPath(KnownFolder.AppData);
  string fp = Path.Combine(apf, "MyApp");
  Directory.CreateDirectory(fp);
}
```

A directory called "MyApp" is created in AppData\LocalLow which is not what I'm looking for.  Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: In fact it does create a directory (here in AppData\Roaming) but it's private to your user and your app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes#appdata-operations-on-windows-10-version-1903-and-later (you can use LocalApplicationData instead but it will be the same, in AppData\Local this time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the features of MSIX is that it automatically redirects writes to AppData to a private per-user, per-app location during execution.

This means that your directory will actually end up in %localappdata%\Packages\PublisherName.AppName_hash\LocalCache\Roaming.

This behaviour is by design and a requirement to keep the promise of clean uninstalls of apps, i.e. that everything is deleted when you remove the app.

If you really want to write to the "real" non-virtualized %AppData% location from an MSIX packaged app, you must disable the file redirections by editing the application manifest as suggested [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-disable-registry-file-redirection.html). Note that this comes with some limitations and is not recommended.